# Which vulnerable website packages are available for testing purposes?

Tags: php, security, web

I'm looking for vulnerable website packages which allow me to test my security practices and help me get a better understanding of attacks I'm unaware of.

I'd like to  find packages written in PHP. I've found [Gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/part1) from Google which looks good, but it's in Python; Are there any others I'm missing? I had a difficult time getting any results from Google.

Comment: Are you looking for vulnerable websites / packages to test your static analysis / security auditing software against or are you looking for that security auditing software to check your own website?

Comment: Pretty much any older version of a popular package is going to have vulnerabilities. Try Wordpress to get a large number of them in one place.

Comment: I'm looking to apply the solutions I'll learn from cracking the vulnerable website to my own websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Damn Vulnerable Web App](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) is a PHP/MySQL web application that is damn vulnerable. Its main goals are to be an aid for security professionals to test their skills and tools in a legal environment, help web developers better understand the processes of securing web applications and aid teachers/students to teach/learn web application security in a class room environment.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reasonable list of vulnerable applications and operating systems **[here](http://r00tsec.blogspot.com/2011/02/pentest-lab-vulnerable-servers.html)**, including the **[OWASP collection](http://code.google.com/p/owaspbwa/)** with WebGoat.

And over on **[Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com)** we have questions like **[this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/183/485)** which list further ones.